# I need a report filter with many account names

Tags: reporting, criteria-filter

I have 128 Accounts. Each account name, for example "account1", has up to 50 identically named accounts for a total of 1313 unique Account IDs.

I need to run a report that lists all 1313 accounts without having to enter 128 different (`Account Name equals account 1`) and 128 logical 1 or 2 or 3... or 128.

Is there a way to create this filter?

I have tried (`Account name equals name1, name2`, `Account name equals "name1", "name2"`, `Account name equals 'name1', 'name2'`)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the list of accounts is known in advance and doesn't change frequently, I'd recommend "cheating" and adding a background field called "Include in Account Group Report" or something.  Then use data loader to check off that field for the 1313 records.  Then your report only has one filter.

I don't know the limits offhand, but I'd be surprised if the report builder allowed 128 different OR criteria on the same report.  And it would be a maintenance nightmare for you.

I'd also recommend digging into the business reason for this request.  A list of 1313 accounts isn't exactly workable.  Are they looking for some aggregate statistic or higher level grouping?  If they need the whole list for excel or something, just export all accounts and delete the spreadsheet rows that they don't need.